# How to use different symbols in dotplot based on vector values

Tags: r, plot, symbols

I have location (coordinates) and environmental data and I would like to create dot plots for each of the environmental variables in the dataset (see sample data and code below). Instead of a single symbol for all of the points in each dot plot (e.g. pch=16), I would like to use a unique symbol determined by the one-degree line of latitude, e.g. abs(latitude).

My R sample dataset:

```
WW_Covs <- structure(list(Latitude = c(62.4419, 67.833333, 65.95, 63.72935,
60.966667, 60.266667, 55.660455, 62.216667, 61.3, 61.4, 62.084139, 55.662566, 
64.48508, 63.208354, 62.87591, 62.70856, 62.64009, 63.79488, 59.55, 62.84206), BIO_02 
= c(87, 82, 75, 70, 77, 70, 59, 84, 84, 79, 85, 60, 91, 87, 74, 74, 76, 70, 76, 74), 
BIO_03 = c(26, 23, 25, 26, 25, 24, 25, 25, 26, 25, 26, 26, 24, 25, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 
24), BIO_04 = c(8443, 9219, 7594, 6939, 7928, 7593, 6160, 8317, 8167, 7972, 8323, 
6170, 9489, 8578, 7814, 7680, 7904, 7149, 7445, 7803), BIO_05 = c(201, 169, 151, 166, 
194, 210, 202, 205, 204, 186, 205, 200, 200, 195, 170, 154, 180, 166, 219, 170), 
BIO_06 = c(-131, -183, -144, -102, -107, -75, -26, -119, -113, -120, -120, -28, -169, 
-143, -131, -142, -124, -111, -72, -129), BIO_08 = c(128, 109, 85, 78, 122, 145, 153, 
134, 130, 126, 132, 152, 120, 119, 115, 98, 124, 104, 147, 115), BIO_09 = c(-31, -81, 
-16, 13, -60, -6, 25, -25, -25, -70, -25, 23, -56, -39, -47, -60, -39, 8, 0, -46),
BIO_12 = c(667, 481, 760, 970, 645, 557, 645, 666, 652, 674, 670, 670, 568, 598, 650, 
734, 620, 868, 571, 658), BIO_13 = c(78, 77, 96, 109, 85, 70, 67, 77, 84, 93, 78, 68, 
72, 78, 93, 99, 90, 96, 72, 93), BIO_15 = c(23, 40, 25, 21, 36, 30, 21, 24, 28, 34, 
24, 22, 28, 29, 34, 32, 36, 22, 30, 34), BIO_19 = c(147, 85, 180, 236, 108, 119, 154, 
149, 135, 118, 148, 162, 117, 119, 120, 141, 111, 204, 111, 122)), .Names = 
c("Latitude", "BIO_02", "BIO_03", "BIO_04", "BIO_05", "BIO_06", "BIO_08", "BIO_09", 
"BIO_12", "BIO_13", "BIO_15", "BIO_19"), row.names = c(1:20), class = "data.frame")
```

My R dotplot code:

```
library(lattice)    
dotplot(as.matrix(WW_Covs[,-c(1:8)]), groups = FALSE,
            strip = strip.custom(bg = 'white', par.strip.text = list(cex = 0.8)), 
            scales = list(x = list(relation = "free"), y = list(relation = "free"), 
            draw = FALSE), col = 1, cex  = 0.5, pch = 16, xlab = "Value of the variable",
            ylab = "Order of the data from text file")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've imported your data as `en` (easy name :) ). Let me know if I understood your problem and if this is what you're after.

```
library(lattice)
floor <- as.factor(floor(en$Latitude))

dotplot(as.matrix(en[,-c(1:8)]), groups = FALSE,
  strip = strip.custom(bg = 'white', par.strip.text = list(cex = 0.8)), 
  scales = list(x = list(relation = "free"), y = list(relation = "free"), 
    draw = FALSE), col = 1, cex  = 1, pch = floor, xlab = "Value of the variable",
  ylab = "Order of the data from text file")
```

[image]

*update*

If you want to change the plotting symbols, you could change the corresponding levels of `floor`.

```
> levels(floor)
[1] "55" "59" "60" "61" "62" "63" "64" "65" "67"
> levels(floor) <- 1:length(levels(floor)) 
> levels(floor)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9"
```

Comment: I get an error when running this under R 2.14.1: `Error in dotplot(as.matrix(en[, -c(1:8)]), groups = FALSE, strip = strip.custom(bg = "white",  : 
  argument 6 matches multiple formal arguments`

Comment: 2.14.2 and lattice_0.20-0 over here. You?

Comment: `2.14.1` and lattice `0.20-0`, hmmmm

Comment: The problem was the library call that was edited into the question (`epicalc`). Just loading lattice works...I edited the question.

Comment: Yes I forgot to put the commend line for lattice in my sample code. Sorry for the error.

Comment: Now I see how to replace the value(s) for a symbol in a dotplot. But, I still do not know how to change the symbols as the vector "latitude" is out of range (e.g. 55 to 65) for the symbol set available for the "pch" parameter (0 to 25, plus a few symbols).

Comment: It works like a charm and if I order my data by the variable "Latitude" the patterns become much more clear.